# Caffe - Use ".caffemodel " file with Python->C++ file translated layers

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I have a `.prototxt` file and a `.caffemodel` file, for a network I built and trained in **py-caffe**, using **self developed Python layers**.

Later, I implemented the same layers for the C++ version of Caffe.

The question is whether it is possible to only change the layer types (from the Python ones to the C++ ones) in the `.prototxt` file, while using the same already trained `.caffemodel` file, in order to load and use the trained network, this time with the C++ layers?

Comment: does your layer has internal parameters? that is, did you use `self.blobs.add_blob()` in your `"Python"` layer implementation?

Comment: I didn't. Does it mean I can just implement the C++ methods to do the same as the Python ones? Actually that's logical as the scheme is defined in the `.prototxt` file and not in the layer implementation

Comment: if you don't have internal parameters than the layer has no effect on the loading of `.caffemodel` you should be okay converting it from python to cpp. I suppose you'll be even better off having a GPU implementation (`.cu` implementation...)

Comment: Is it a problem if in the `prototxt` file, I have a `python_param` clause inside the python layer definition?

Comment: It's not a problem at all to have layer's parameters in the prototxt file. Look at other layers' c++ implementation to see how prtototxt parameters are handled in c++ code. You can then consider whether you want to define parameters for your net or to use `python_param` and read it in c++ from the prototxt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it's possible. In case you have layer parameters, you should add a new layer_param message to caffe.proto, and read them accordingly in your cpp layer.
For example, [PVANet caffe repository](https://github.com/sanghoon/caffe/blob/6068dd04ea93cca9fcee036628fdb3ea95b4ebcd/src/caffe/layers/proposal_layer.cpp) has implementation for the original Python proposal layer.
As you can see in [caffe.proto](https://github.com/sanghoon/caffe/blob/6068dd04ea93cca9fcee036628fdb3ea95b4ebcd/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto), a new message was added to hold the Python layer's parameters -
// Message that stores parameters used by ProposalLayer

```
message ProposalParameter {
  optional uint32 feat_stride = 1 [default = 16];
  optional uint32 base_size = 2 [default = 16];
  optional uint32 min_size = 3 [default = 16];
  repeated float ratio = 4;
  repeated float scale = 5;
  optional uint32 pre_nms_topn = 6 [default = 6000];
  optional uint32 post_nms_topn = 7 [default = 300];
  optional float nms_thresh = 8 [default = 0.7];
}
```

The original train / test prototxt contains the following layer:

```
layer {
  name: 'proposal'
  type: 'Python'
  bottom: 'rpn_cls_prob_reshape'
  bottom: 'rpn_bbox_pred'
  bottom: 'im_info'
  top: 'rpn_rois'
  top: 'rpn_scores'
  include { phase: TRAIN }
  python_param {
    module: 'rpn.proposal_layer'
    layer: 'ProposalLayer'
    param_str: "{'feat_stride': 16, 'ratios': [0.333, 0.5, 0.667, 1, 1.5, 2, 3], 'scales': [2, 3, 5, 9, 16, 32]}"
  }
}
```

When the new cpp one looks like:

```
layer {
  name: 'proposal'
  type: 'proposal'
  bottom: 'rpn_cls_prob_reshape'
  bottom: 'rpn_bbox_pred'
  bottom: 'im_info'
  top: 'rpn_rois'
  top: 'rpn_scores'
  include { phase: TRAIN }
  proposal_param {
    feat_stride: 16
    ratios: 0.333, 0.5, 0.667, 1, 1.5, 2, 3
    scales: 2, 3, 5, 9, 16, 32
  }
}
```

etc.